# Anime where people mutate from an explosion?

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this anime in a quick commercial or ad on Facebook or Instagram.

What I remember is a man sees someone that he may know and either they are holding a briefcase or someone else is but it explodes whatever is inside gets one the man and he starts to mutate or grow an exoskeleton.

I think it's a newer anime but not 100%. When the briefcase explodes it does a decent amount of damage.